# powershell command's output show only one column

Tags: powershell, format

```
PS C:\script> $a
Caption              DeviceID            Model                Partitions  Size
Intel Raid 1 Volume  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  Intel Raid 1 Volume  2           456116451840
Intel Raid 1 Volume  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  Intel Raid 1 Volume  1           1900409817600
```

How can I only list the DeviceID column?
Desired output:

```
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
```

Comment: How did you obtain whatever's in `$a`?

Comment: `$a | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceId` probably.

Comment: Probably, yes. Hard to say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$a` is a valid PSObject, you can achieve this using either the `-Property` parameter or `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object` cmdlet.

The difference being, using `-Property` parameter means that you're just specifying a Property to select. That's it. But if you're using `-ExpandProperty` parameter, you'll be specifying a property to select as well as prompting PowerShell to make an attempt to expand that property (in case the property itself is an Array or an Object).

Since in your use case, the property DeviceId is a normal NoteProperty, you can simply use something like this:

```
$a | Select-Object -Property DeviceId
```